# wpf System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog preselected PrintQueue (printer) is ignored

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog, printqueue

I want to show the `PrintDialog` from `System.Windows.Controls`.
I also want to preselect a specific printer in some cases.
I tried it this way:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), printerName);
```

and also this way:

```
PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer();
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintQueue = printServer.GetPrintQueue(printerName);
```

But in both cases the default printer is preselected, not the printer I defined in `printerName`.
Anyone an idea why this can be or what I can do better?

Edit:
It seems to always be the default printer set by the OS not what I define in the `PrintDialog.PrintQueue`...

Comment: I can't use `LocalPrintServer` because we need to also address the network printers.